# Is this a proper use of "by the way" and "along"?

Tags: phrase-requests

Can I say:

You will create (name some project) and learn (name some skill) by the way.

You will create (name some project) and learn (name some skill) along the way.

?

Are both sentences correct? I want to say that someone will learn something accidentally while creating some project.

Comment: "By the way" is more normally used to indicate a sort of parenthesis than to describe an incidental effect of an action (which is how you have used it in your example). An example of the more normal usage is "Thank you for giving me this appointment to discuss my loan, I like your suit by the way". The point is that the customer's opinion of the bank employee's suit has no bearing on the loan decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second sentence "You will create (name some project) and learn (name some skill) along the way." is better but you could say "by doing so" instead of "by the way" in the first sentence and it would also be correct.